# How to change minimum stability for just one package in Composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to incorporate the [ldap-auth](https://github.com/ccovey/ldap-auth) module into my Laravel project via Composer. However, it is only available in a `dev` stability version. My current Composer.json has a `minimum-stability` set to `stable`, which I'd like to keep for the rest of my modules, but when I try to run `composer update`, it gives an error that there is a module that does not meet the minimum stability requirements. Is there a way to install that package separately with its own minimum-stability requirement?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is, you'll just need to whitelist that package with a stability flag. Something like this:

```
{
"require": {
   "ccovey/ldap-auth": "1.1.*@dev",
}}
```

[Composer Stability Flags](https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html)