# Set yii2-jeasyui for yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to use `JEASYUI` for yii2 by installing [yii2-jeasyui](https://github.com/sheillendra/yii2-jeasyui) but I'm facing some problems. I cannot successfully use composer :

```
php composer.phar require sheillendra/yii2-jeasyui "dev-master"
```

due to `shiellendra/yii2-theme` package not found. so I installed it manually. Although, the problem remain because the theme folder is missing.

Can somebody help me install correctly, even manually ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case somebody have the same problem, this can help. The problem is due to the `composer` file specifications. Just need to change :

```
"minimum-stability": "stable",
```

to :

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```

because `yii2-jeasyui` is not already stable.

Comment: A more complicated solution, but likely better for production situations, is to make an exception flag for the one package that is needed. 

Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240571/how-to-change-minimum-stability-for-just-one-package-in-composer Further reading: https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html

Comment: Better to still prefer stable version like:     "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,

Answer (score 2):

Working solution for composer.json:

```
"sheillendra/yii2-jeasyui": "@dev"
```

and if you install via console:

```
php composer.phar require sheillendra/yii2-jeasyui "@dev"
```